# Problem in GetRuleViolations method in NerdDinner tutotial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nerddinner

I'm on about page 70 of the NerdDinner tutorial (MVC 1.0 version). It won't build at this point because it is saying the properties referred to in the GetRuleViolations (ie, Title, Description, etc) can't be resolved. I've compared my own project with the downloadable source code and can't figure out what is missing. The error VS 2008 is giving me is "The name 'Title' does not exist in the current context". I can see the declarations in the NerDinner.designer.cs file.

Comment: May we see the section of code it's pointing to?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to import the namespace of the model type?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. So, this is in the Dinner.cs file, which is in the Namespace NerdDinner.Models. For that reason, I didn't think I needed explicitly import it. I must be missing something then.

Also, I assume by "import" you mean a "using NerdDinner.Models" declaration.

What am I not getting?